# click event in checkboxes angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, checkbox, angular8

I need to show a form and hide a form using ngif when a click event takes place in a  check box.

my column header and my column values code

```
  <th><label class="btn btn-filter">
    <input type="checkbox" name="allTrades" [value]="trade" (change)="allTrades($event)"> status
  </label>&nbsp;</th>
```

I have the status column name and have a checkbox nearby

```
 <td><ng-container *ngFor="let trd of trade">
    <label class="btn btn-filter">
      <input type="checkbox" name="trades" [checked]="trd.selected" (change)="yourfunc($event)" (change)="handleSelected($event)">{{ trd.label}}
    </label>&nbsp;
  </ng-container></td>
```

I have the values of the status column and I have wrote in such a way that when I click the checkbox in my column header all the checkbox values in the column gets enabled and vice versa

The content I wanna show when checkbox gets enabled

What I need is that I wanna show the contents of this html chunk when the checkbox gets enabled and it should be hiddeen when the checkbox gets disabled.

```
    <div *ngif=ischeck>
  
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" >
        <input class="toolbar-search" type="text" matInput autocomplete="off" >
        <mat-placeholder>Name</mat-placeholder>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" >
        <input class="toolbar-search" type="text" matInput autocomplete="off">
        <mat-placeholder>City</mat-placeholder>
    </mat-form-field>

</div>
```

my ts. Here the handleSelected($event) is the click event function I am trying to hide the html

```
 trade = [
  { label: ' Check', selected: false }, 

];



 allTrades(event) {
      const checked = event.target.checked;
      this.trade.forEach(item => item.selected = checked);
    }



handleSelected($event) {
  if ($event.target.checked === true) {
  // Handle your code
  this.ischeck=true

  }
```

}

NOTE: the checkbox code written here is in such a way that I have a checkbox near column name and when I enable it all checkboxes in column values gets enabled and vice versa.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zahy1b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

My stackblitz link. When I click the status check box automatically the other checkbox repeates the same. That part I have done. What I need is that I wanted to display the content in div tag when the checkbox is enabled

Comment: i really tried but I could not understand what is it that you are trying to achieve and could not... 
I think you are better off creating a snipped of your code here: https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy
and updating your question

Comment: I have posted the stackblitz link bro. I have also expalined in my question further. Please help if you can. @TheFabio

Comment: .Hope this one helps @TheFabio

Comment: the correct syntax for a ngif is`*ngIf` if you fix it it works

Comment: I know I made a mistake in that one. But No it doesnt work. can u update the stackblitz and post @TheFabio

Comment: If i got it right, you want to display a div when a trade is selected, right? if that is the case this should resolve it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kfycuc

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the state of checked in the model you are using, not a separated `isChecked` variable...

Here is a working solution
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kfycuc

move the div into the `ng-container`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let trd of trade">
  <label class="btn btn-filter">
    <input type="checkbox" name="trades" [checked]="trd.selected"  (change)="handleSelected($event, trd)">{{ trd.label}}
  </label>&nbsp;

  <div *ngIf="trd.selected">
    <h1>Heey</h1>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

and change your handler to update the model:

```
handleSelected($event, trd) {
  trd.selected = $event.target.checked;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for trying but its not working in my real case scenario.

Comment: It comes under in the td values in the table which is messy and not what I want

Comment: Can you do it in a different method which doesnt involved td tag closing at last and write a seperate event handler

Comment: is the intention to have the text displayed if any of the trade items is "selected"? or when exactly do you need it displayed?